# Lualatex: cannot use bold cambria

Tags: fonts, fontspec, linux

I use ArchLinux and TeXLive 2022, LuaHBTeX 1.15.0, with cambriab.ttf cambriai.ttf cambria.ttc cambriaz.ttf located in /usr/local/share/fonts/c

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}

\begin{document}
    abcd \textbf{abcd}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

and a warning

```
Font shape `TU/Cambria(0)/b/n' undefined
(Font)  using `TU/Cambria(0)/m/n' instead.
```

PS: I have installed all 5 Cambria (R, B, I, BI, Math) fonts from Windows.

Comment: Please let us know which version of the Windows operating system and which TeX distribution you employ. The reason I ask is that I am unable to reproduce the issue you report on my MacBook laptop computer (MacOS 12.6 "Monterey", MacTeX 2022, LuaHBTeX 1.15.0, LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5), with the `Cambria.ttf` and `Cambria Bold.ttf` font files located in `/Library/Fonts/Microsoft/`.

Comment: I use ArchLinux and TeXLive 2022, LuaHBTeX 1.15.0, with `cambriab.ttf cambriai.ttf cambria.ttc cambriaz.ttf` located in `/usr/local/share/fonts/c`

Comment: What happens if you change `\setmainfont{Cambria}` to `\setmainfont{Cambria}[BoldFont=CambriaB]`?

Comment: It works! @Mico

Comment: Great! In recent years, the utility packages that `fontspec` relies on to map font descriptors into actual file names on various operating systems have actually become rather good. Nevertheless, as you've discovered, a bit of extra help is still needed from time to time. If you haven't already done so, do take the time to acquaint yourself thoroughly with the user guide of the [fontspec](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package. It'll be time well spent.

Comment: Note Cambria isn't usually licenced for use on Linux, you could use the Google font Caladea which is metric compatible and probably pre-installed.

Comment: `\setmainfont{Cambria}[BoldFont=CambriaB,BoldItalicFont=CambriaZ]` Only bold and bolditalic is abnormal, italic font is good.

Comment: @Mico I tested on Windows 11 and found that `[BoldFont=CambriaB]` is still necessary, I don't know why Mac is different from others. I use lualatex.

Comment: @Firestar-Reimu - It's not LuaLaTeX itself that makes the connection between a semi-abstract declaration such as `\setmainfont{Cambria}[BoldFont=CambriaB]` and the actual names of the files -- `Cambria.ttf` and `Cambria Bold.ttf` in the MacOS case. Instead, it's the `luaotfload-tool` utility that makes the connection, at the operating system level. Various OSs are known to be sometimes more, and sometimes less, helpful towards the tasks that `luaotfload-tool` has to perform. I'll readily admit to not having the slightest idea of how `luaotfload-tool` actually does its job...

Comment: There still is something strange. With a very recent install of TeXLive on Windows 11, using the system fonts I get luaotfload-tool which is able to locate both `Cambria` and `CambriaBold` right as  `"c:/Windows/Fonts/cambria.ttc"` and `"c:/Windows/Fonts/cambriab.ttf"` but I still need to specify the variant with `\setmainfont{Cambria}[BoldFont=CambriaB]` otherwise lualatex does not see it.

Comment: So, the answer is to use
`\setmainfont{Cambria.ttc}`
with the extension made explicit.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS we have:

```
H-MacBook:Python voss$ luafindfont Cambria
  No.        Filename Symbolic name                                Path
   1.     Cambria.otf     cambria  /Users/voss/Library/Fonts/Cambria/
   2.    CambriaB.ttf     cambria  /Users/voss/Library/Fonts/Cambria/
   3.    CambriaI.ttf     cambria  /Users/voss/Library/Fonts/Cambria/
   4. CambriaMath.otf cambriamath  /Users/voss/Library/Fonts/Cambria/
   5.    CambriaZ.ttf     cambria  /Users/voss/Library/Fonts/Cambria/
```

The symbolic names are not correctly set inside the font files: LuaTeX is unable to find italic, bold, ...  However, in my installation there is no BoldItalic, the reason why I have to fake it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria.otf}[
    BoldFont=CambriaB.ttf,
    ItalicFont=CambriaI.ttf,
    BoldItalicFont=CambriaI.ttf,
    BoldItalicFeatures={RawFeature={embolden=5}}
]

\begin{document}
    abcd \textbf{abcd} \textit{abcd}
    \textbf{\textit{abcd}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just curious: Which versions of MacOS and MacTeX do you employ? The reason I ask is that on my system (MacOS 12.6, MacTeX 2022), and with the five cambria files stored in `/Library/Fonts/Microsoft/`, it suffices to run `\setmainfont{Cambria}` to access both font weights (medium, bold) and both font shapes (upright, slanted).

Comment: I am curious about that issue too. I had TeXLive installed on Windows from about year back and I could use `\setmainfont{Cambria}` and get all the variants. 
I changed my machine and reinstalled TeXLive from scratch, rsync'ing from the main repo. And now I need to specify the fonts for the variants. So something must have changed somewhere.

Comment: run `luafindfont cambria` and check if all variants are found. Are you running XeLaTeX or Lualatex?

Comment: Isn’t `CambriaZ.ttf` the bold italic?

Comment: yes, that is true. But it is often missing ...